# Laptop battery causes jitter in laptop-response

Tags: laptop, troubleshooting, battery

I've got an older laptop (Acer Aspire 1640) that responds terribly when the battery is actually inserted. The mouse-movement is very jittery, and it seems though the entire system is sluggish too. When the battery is removed, and the laptop is operating off of the adapter, it works just fine. Does anybody know what may cause this, and whether or not I can remedy it? At the very least, if I could have the battery inserted without the laptop detecting it, that would be sufficient - without the battery the laptop doesn't sit flat, and wobbles like a bad wal-mart shopping cart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would be curious if your battery may be causing some form of interference with the electrical signals that are generated by the keyboard/mouse. I doubt it would be possible for you to check with a different battery.

**Edit**: This is including extra idea(s) and information discussed in the comments...

- Attempt to determine whether or not USB keyboards/mice will have the same problem as the built-in.
- Try to keep the connection between battery and laptop broken by either damaging the leads (potentially dangerous) or covering the leads with strips of electrical tape.

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have another. I was wondering if I can some how break the leads between the batter and laptop - is that safe? It would fix my balance-issue at the very least.

Comment: Jonathan: I am doing some searching for battery bypass methods that would potentially allow you to keep the battery in without having to worry about it possibly interfering. You should count yourself at least lucky enough to have a laptop that works without a battery if it's plugged in.

Comment: This laptop has been good to me over the years. Whether or not it works with a battery is irrelevant. I just love having her feed me hulu through my 42'' big screen :)

Comment: Jonathan Sampson: I forgot to ask...do you still get the same problems if you happen to be using a USB keyboard or mouse?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.

Comment: If you are still getting the same problems with a usb keyboard and mouse, then my initial idea about there being some sort of interference may be inaccurate. The more and more I search to no avail, the more and more I think I like the idea of you going and either breaking the leads between the battery/laptop or somehow just covering them up so that the connection can't be made while still being able to jam the battery in there.

Comment: I might be wrong about the usb-devices. I've not used them in a while. Rather than breaking leads, I might just try a strip of electrical tape.

Comment: Update your answer to cover your perspective on the leads, and covering/breaking them and I can accept your answer based upon what unfolded in these comments.